# Riesz representation theorem in a Sobolev space on an interval

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I already proved that there exists a unique function $u\in H_0^1((-1;1))$ such that $\int_{-1}^{1} u' \phi'dx=\phi(0)$ $\forall \phi \in C_0^\infty((-1;1))$.

I want to find this $u$.
I have found this function that satisfies the condition
$$
u(x)=
\begin{cases}
0.5(1+x) &\text{ if } x\leq0,\\
0.5(1-x) &\text{ if } x>0
\end{cases}
$$
We have that
$$
u'(x)=
\begin{cases}
0.5 &\text{ if } x\leq0,\\
-0.5 &\text{ if } x>0
\end{cases}
$$
And using the fundamental theorem of calculus we obtain that
$\int_{-1}^{1} u' \phi'dx=\phi(0)$.

However $u$ is not compactly supported. Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function $u$ is the correct one, and it is in $H^1_0((-1,1))$. The notation $H^1_0$ does not mean the function is compactly supported. The space $H^1_0$ is the **closure** of compactly supported (smooth) functions with respect to the $H^1$ norm.

For each $n$, the function $u_n(x)=\max(0, u(x)-1/n)$ is compactly supported in $(-1,1)$. One can mollify it, obtaining smooth compactly supported functions; hence, $u_n\in H_0^1((-1,1))$. As $n\to\infty$, we have $u_n\to u$ in the $H^1$ norm, hence $u$  is also in $H^1_0$.